# How to remove field from object conditionally, by other ENUM field value

Tags: java, enums

I have a class as follows and SelectedFormat is an Enum.

Main object class

```
public class ABC {

    private SelectedFormat selectedFormat;
    private JsonArrayVo jsonArray;
}
```

SelectedFormat

```
public enum SelectedFormat {
    TEXT("TEXT"), JSON( "JSON");
}
```

I need to remove "jsonArray" field in order to the value of selectedFormat. In this case, jsonArray applicable only when selectedFormat is JSON

Comment: what do you mean by "remove" ? assign null?

Comment: `if (selectedFormat == SelectedFormat.TEXT) jsonArray = null` i will send you an invoice at my hourly rate

Comment: @Michael You should use `Optional<>` for this, I'll send an invoice for the code review. (by the way, did you just use a clue-branch? :P )

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica Please send it to my secretary, they'll handle the details :)

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake was to make `SelectedFormat` an enumeration.

You should instead model an interface `Format` an two classes `TextFormat` and `JSonFormat` which implement the interface.

```
interface Format { ... }

class TextFormat implements Format {...}

class JsonFormat implements Format {
   private JsonArrayVo valueObject;
}
```

Comment: I agree, the mistake is allowing invalid state in the original object. Trying to fix the problem after the fact with an `if` statement is adding insult to injury.